# Count length of sequence of equal numbers in a vector

Tags: r, vector

Consider a vector `c(1,1,1,0,1,1)`.

The idea is to count each sequence of equal numbers, e.g.

1. length of equal numbers, i.e. 1,1,1 is 3
2. length of equal numbers, i.e. 0 is 1
3. length of equal numbers, i.e. 1,1 is 2

I have written a code to transform all numbers in either 1 or 0. Does it make sense to extract the sequence of equal numbers to a new vector and use table function to count? Or is there another way?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `rle`:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,0,1,1)
rle(x)
# Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:3] 3 1 2
#  values : num [1:3] 1 0 1
```